# Excel line graph with data range

Tags: excel, graph, range, line

I have a problem with excel line graph. I want to line graph, but my data set contains data range rather than exact value. For example;

variables x,y;

x = {1,2,3,4} and y = {2-4, 8-16, 7-3.5 , 2-5}

when x = 1, y is in the range of 2 and 4 and goes on like that. I hope I can identify the problem. How can I plot graph for this kind of a data set? Or Can I plot with excel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Start with your data (below left) and insert a column between min and max that computes the span, or max minus min (below right).

Select the shaded region of this new range and insert a stacked area chart (top chart below). Format the bottom area to use no fill color.

[image: stacked area chart]

Comment: Worth noting that this is only a partial solution: if the values on x are not evenly distributed this produces a misleading plot.  E.g., if x={1,2,15,50} and you use this method, the plot will come out looking identical to the one above except with the labels changed (i.e. the x-axis is actually plotting categories, not a number line).  I don't know of any solution to this, just thought I'd point it out

Comment: For more complicated data sets, you can follow my tutorial [Fill Under or Between Series in an Excel XY Chart](https://peltiertech.com/fill-under-between-series-in-excel-chart/).

Comment: Nice tutorial! Thanks! I'll definitely be using that method next week